# what is this sed command doing: sed '1!G;h'

Tags: sed

I'm trying to understand sed better but one thing is throwing me off despite going through the online docs and man page repeatedly.

If I do: (inside of `bash`)

```
echo "
alpha
beta
gamma" | sed '1!G;h'
```

I see:

```
alpha
beta
alpha
gamma
beta
alpha
```

So I get that `1!G` adds a new line after each input line except for line 1. And then `h` copies the pattern space into the hold space. But nothing happens with the hold space, and the pattern space should be output, which at this point I would expect to see `1!G;h` giving exactly the same output as `1!G`, which is:

```
alpha
beta

gamma
```

Is the hold space being output somehow? If the hold space is just output after the pattern space for each line, then why doesn't `sed 'h'` double each line?

Oh I am running this on macOS Mojave with `bash` 5. I can't tell which version of `sed` is being used, but it's the base one that comes with the most recent macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget that `G` appends from the hold space, which your first command writes to, but not your second.

`sed h` is not doubling every line, because it's just overwriting the hold space in every cycle.

Your first command is equivalent to

```sh
sed '1!G;h' <<END_INPUT
alpha
beta
gamma
END_INPUT
```

and outputs

```
alpha
beta
alpha
gamma
beta
alpha
```

For all but the first line, it appends the current hold space to the pattern space with a delimiting newline character. It then overwrites the hold space with the pattern space.  At the end of every cycle (after processing a line of input), there's an implicit `p` (print) command.

Another way of saying it is "for each line of input, it outputs all the previous lines in reverse (with the new line last)".

So the code would

1. read `alpha` into the pattern space, copy `alpha` into the hold space, print `alpha`,
2. read `beta` into the pattern space, append `\nalpha` to the pattern space from the hold space, copy `beta\nalpha` to the hold space, print `beta\nalpha`,
3. read `gamma` into the pattern space, append `\nbeta\nalpha` to the pattern space from the hold space, copy `gamma\nbeta\nalpha` to the hold space, print `gamma\nbeta\nalpha`.

The code

```sh
sed '1!G' <<END_INPUT
alpha
beta
gamma
END_INPUT
```

outputs

```
alpha
beta

gamma
```

(the third and last lines are empty).

This `sed` code outputs each line of input, and will add an extra newline to all but the first line. It does this because it will

1. read `alpha` into the pattern space, print `alpha`,
2. read `beta` into the pattern space, append `\n` to the pattern space from the hold space, print `beta\n`,
3. read `gamma` into the pattern space, append `\n` to the pattern space from the hold space, print `gamma\n`.

Note that the appending from the hold space with `G` here just adds an extra newline at the end of the pattern space since it's always empty (since you never write to it).

Answer (score 1):

I found out by trying:

```
]# echo  -e "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf" |sed '1!G;h' 
a
b
a
c
b
a
d
c
b
a
e
d
c
b
a
f
e
d
c
b
a
```

If you read backwards: "abcdef", then "abcde", then "abcd", "abc", "ab", "a".

What you call that?

It works, because "G" adds, and "h" replaces. If you leave just `G;h` you get additional empty lines between these blocks.

---

`info sed` has a "tac" example:

`sed -n '1!G;$p;h'`

By only printing once (`-n` and `$p`), the result is quite different: it is the last "block" of `sed '1!G;h'`

---

Perl can easily imitate this algorithm with (named) variables:

```
]# echo -e "a\nb\nc" | perl -ne '$hold = $_ . $hold; print $hold;'
a
b
a
c
b
a
```

The reversal comes from the way the line and the saved lines are merged:

```
]# echo  -e "a\nb\nc" |perl -ne '$hold .= $_; print $hold;'
a
a
b
a
b
c
```

`$_` is the input lines. It is H=H+line vs. H=line+H. You have to read `info sed` carefully to find this, and other subtleties.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with something simpler:

```
$ seq 4 | sed 'G;h'
1

2
1

3
2
1

4
3
2
1
```

Each block adds a new number and prints it in reverse order.
Why is that happening? Let's walk slowly the process:

1. The first number from seq (a `1`) (the first line) is received by sed. That line is placed in the pattern space.
2. The first command to execute is `G`, that appends one newline followed by the **hold space** to the present pattern space. At first (as here) the hold space is empty, so sed appends a newline and the empty string (of the hold space) to the present pattern space. In short, it appends a newline to the first line from the input.
3. The second command is `h`. That copy the pattern space to the hold space. Now, the hold space contains a `1` followed by a newline.
4. The list of commands has ended, so sed prints the pattern space (a `1` followed by a newline) because there is no `-n` option to sed. Then it loops to the next input line.
5. Now sed receives the second line, a `2`, placing it in the pattern space.
6. The first command is G. So, sed appends the hold space (a `1` and a newline, as above, written in a shorter form: `1\n`) to the pattern space. Now the pattern space holds `2\n1\n`.
7. What the pattern space holds gets printed. Sed loops back.
8. On the third line, `G` appends `\n2\n1\n` to the `3`.
9. The pattern space `3\n2\n1\n` is copied to the hold space with `h`.
10. Also, the pattern space gets printed at the end of the sed script.
11. Loop and repeat till the last line.

All the above amounts to capturing the lines in reverse order.

This script may make things clearer (quote the pattern space with `l`):

```
$ seq 5 | sed -n 'G;h;l'
1\n$
2\n1\n$
3\n2\n1\n$
4\n3\n2\n1\n$
5\n4\n3\n2\n1\n$
```

And, as your original script we avoid adding a newline on the first line:

```
$ seq 5 | sed -n '1!G;h;l'
1$
2\n1$
3\n2\n1$
4\n3\n2\n1$
5\n4\n3\n2\n1$
```

Now, using alpha, beta and gamma:

```
$ printf 'alpha\nbeta\ngamma' | sed -n '1!G;h;l'
alpha$
beta\nalpha$
gamma\nbeta\nalpha$
```

And we get back to the original sed script:

```
$ printf 'alpha\nbeta\ngamma' | sed '1!G;h'
alpha
beta
alpha
gamma
beta
alpha
```

Which actually, IMO, should have been:

```
$ printf 'alpha\nbeta\ngamma' | sed '1!G;h;$!d'
gamma
beta
alpha
```

Only printing the last iteration with all lines in reverse order.